# how to get the element a if its href has no contents, in selenium C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown current-user" dropdown="" on-toggle="toggled(open)">
    <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" href="" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle="">
        <img src="assets/images/avatar-1.jpg"alt="{{user.FirstName}}">    
        <span class="username">
            {{user.FirstName}} <i class="ti-angle-down"> </i>    </i>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="Account/LogOff" ng-href="Account/LogOff">
            Log Out
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now in my site, i need to click on link which has another sub links like profile, log out etc. how to find that super link and than click on sublink.

Comment: Does this xpath help? `"//a[@href='']/following::a"`

Comment: `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='']/following::a"))`

Comment: umm no error saying "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with".

Comment: Scroll and bring the `a` tag into view of the browser.

Comment: Assuming there's only one element like it..  driver.FindElements(By.Tagname("a")).ToList().Where(p=>p.GetAttribute("href") == "");

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

//Scroll the element into view
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()");

//Now, execute findElement
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='']/following::a"));
```

Comment: error says : document.getElementsByTagName(...)[1].scrollIntoViewIfNeeded is not a function (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)